# Can I use SwiftyJSON to get at error contents in Siesta?

Tags: siesta-swift

I'm writing a test for my Siesta-based class, and I'm trying to access the error I received from the server.  In my object, I configured the service like so:

```
    self.service.configure {
        $0.config.pipeline[.parsing].add(SwiftyJSONTransformer, contentTypes: ["*/json"])

        // other configuration setup
    }
```

My test contains the following:

```
    api.fetchApiToken(libraryRequiringAuth).onSuccess({ _ in
        // Then
        XCTFail("Expected request failure, got success")
    }).onFailure({ [weak self] (error) in
        XCTAssertEqual(error.httpStatusCode, expectedStatusCode)
        let serverError: JSON? = error.entity?.typedContent()
        XCTAssertEqual(serverError![0]["title"].string, expectedErrorMessage)
        print("Expected error is: \(error)")
        XCTAssertNil(self?.api.bearerAuthHeader)
        expectation.fulfill()
    })
```

The line `let serverError: JSON? = error.entity?.typedContent()` is setting `serverError` to `nil`, but in the debugger, I can see that `error.entity` exists and has the content I expect.  Can I not use SwiftyJSON at this point?

**Edit:**

Here are the contents of the error:

```
Error Error(userMessage: "Forbidden", httpStatusCode: Optional(403), entity: Optional(Siesta.Entity(content: [{
    ipRangeError =     {
        libraryId = 657;
        libraryName = "Test library";
        requestIp = "my.ip.address.was_here";
    };
    status = 403;
    title = "Authentication Failed";
    userData =     {
    };
}], charset: Optional("utf-8"), headers: ["content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"], timestamp: 490978565.82571602)), cause: nil, timestamp: 490978565.825499)
```

Comment: You can definitely get the error content in Siesta. It looks like a type mismatch issue. Would you log the error response and post that? (`print(error.dynamicType, error)` in `onFailure`)

Comment: As a work-around, I found that `let serverError = JSON(error.jsonArray)` works, but I'd still like to be able to use `typedContent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `SwiftyJSONTransformer` is leaving errors untouched. Try configuring it with `transformErrors: true`:

```
private let SwiftyJSONTransformer =
  ResponseContentTransformer(transformErrors: true)
    { JSON($0.content as AnyObject) }
```

Without that flag, the error entity is still an `NSDictionary` instead of a SwiftyJSON `JSON`, and `typedContent()` sees those as mismatched types and gives you a nil.

(And to the question in the title: yes, you can get the full error content, as well as response headers and any underlying `ErrorType` / `NSError` info from the underlying networking layer.)